# ng-options filter in a bs-select cannot access service scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ng-options, angular-strap, angular-filters

**Update: Plnkr** http://plnkr.co/edit/iYmShY6uDaYxktyCYolk?p=preview

I'm creating an angularstrap dropdown with the following code.

```
{{userService.current.id}} <!-- Outputs correct id (1) -->
<button 
ng-if="userService.current.id || !loginService.isLoggedIn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
ng-model="profileService.current" data-placeholder="Profiles" 
ng-options="profile.title for profile in profileService.profiles | 
filter:{userId: userService.current.id}" bs-select>
   Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

The filter in the ng-options is not working/not filtering out as expected. If we change the filter to the following:

```
filter:{userId: 1}
```

It works as expected. So I am assuming something's wrong with the scope of my situation, but I am starting to feel a bit lost in what is potentially wrong as I am still able to print the correct id in the first row of the example.

Is there something wrong with the scope? Or is there something about filter I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Updated with a plunker. Seems like a regular select works fine, but not the angular strap select directive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after endless amounts of time, it is resolved. The way I did it is by simply filtering from the controller using $filter. If there's another, better/more proper resolution, I'd like to hear it. It somehow feels a bit wrong to move the filter into the controller when the filter directive already exists..

http://plnkr.co/edit/iYmShY6uDaYxktyCYolk?p=preview

HTML:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
ng-model="profileService.current" data-placeholder="Profiles" 
ng-options="profile.title for profile in filteredProfiles" bs-select="">
                Action         <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
```

Filter:

```
.filter('filterProfiles', function() {
  return function(id, profiles) {
  var filteredProfiles = [];
    angular.forEach(profiles, function(value, key) {
      if (value.userId == id) {
        filteredProfiles.push(value);
      }
    });
    return filteredProfiles;
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $filter, userService, profileService) {
$scope.$watch('userService.current', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.filteredProfiles = $filter('filterProfiles')($scope.userService.current.id, $scope.profileService.profiles);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you yet found a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope. Better solution is put on hold, 'til then this will have to do.